# Is it ok to place Microdata attributes on vuejs tags?

Tags: html, vue.js, microdata

In our site we have product detail pages built with vuejs which include some non-standard HTML elements. e.g. we have the following to show the average rating for a product

```
<rating :stars="5"
        :rating="@Model.Rating"
        size="'large'"></rating>
```

Vuejs then transforms the above markup within the browser to show a number of star icons, producing quite different HTML markup for the browser.
We need to add support for Schema.org. Is it ok to add the `itemprop="ratingValue"` attribute to the above element e.g.:

```
<rating :stars="5"
        :rating="@Model.Rating"
        size="'large'"
        itemprop="@Model.Rating"></rating>
```

or does Microdata require that the attributes are placed on standard HTML elements?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/

> Note that as of now, Google and Bing can index synchronous JavaScript
>   applications just fine. Synchronous being the key word there. If your
>   app starts with a loading spinner, then fetches content via Ajax, the
>   crawler will not wait for you to finish. This means if you have
>   content fetched asynchronously on pages where SEO is important, SSR
>   might be necessary.

If you render your content server side your schema.org tags will work, but if the content which contains your tag is rendered after an API request or other asynchronous actions then a search engine will not be able to see your tags.

Note: `itemprop="@Model.Rating"` is probably not going to do what you want, you probably want to `:itemprop="@Model.Rating"` or else you're going to get the literal `@Model.Rating` as the value of itemprop.

Comment: The content is rendered server-side, but on further examination here http://schema.org/AggregateRating I think we should probably be rendering this info in the page as JSON data.

Comment: Whatever is easiest to implement.  Also to address `does schema.org require that the attributes are placed on standard html elements?`.  Vue renders regular html.

Comment: I know vue renders standard HTML client side, but the search engines which use the schema.org attributes look at the server side generated markup of the page.

Comment: If you render server side then whatever the client gets, google's webcrawler gets. https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/crawling-indexing/ `When crawlers find a webpage, our systems render the content of the page, just as a browser does.`